# Storing user profile images, privacy policy question

Tags: android, image

I am about to release an Android app. It requires users to upload photos. While developing it, I used Cloudinary. Can I still use it in release version or do I need to create my own storage? If I can (and to me, feels like I can), what should I add into the privacy policy about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, reviewing the privacy policy provided by Cloudinary, I don't think user's data is at risk. They've mentioned that details to supply into their database wouldn't be shared with anyone else. However, they are legally obligated to fulfill the legal requirements of providing any information to the authorities on demand (that applies to many cloud hosting corporations). However, you must take the following point into consideration:

> The content you upload to the Service, whether from your own device or from a cloud-based hosting service, including any data, text, graphic, audio and audio-visual files, may include personally identifiable information. The content that you upload and designate as public, will be accessible to others.
>   [Privacy Policy](https://cloudinary.com/privacy)

Based on further research, when a image is uploaded, Cloudinary generates a random image ID which will result in a random generated URL (I am assuming this will go directly in your database). That URL seems to be accessible by the public but in order to guess that random URL can be a task in itself (so you must be safe). The reason for this being a public domain is partly be able to share the images for another application/platform via providing the URL... [more info](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520632--Can-our-users-upload-private-images-which-are-not-accessible-through-a-public-URL-)
Now coming to the next part of the question, **using user's information**. 
Firstly, you'll need to create your own ***Privacy Policy*** ([Guidance](https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/privacy-policy-guide)) in which you'll mention all these details. The privacy policy should cover the following points (minimum)

1. What information do you collect - This includes both information entered by the user i.e. phone number, name, etc or information which is collected automatically i.e. HTTP logs, data usage or anything in the background.
2. How do you use the information - For example - email might be used for marketing purposes or resetting forgotten passwords.
3. What information do you share - Are you sharing information with third parties (for marketing, survey or any other purposes) or other users?

Therefore, privacy policy is a major subject which I would recommend you to learn in-depth as it's a

> a statement or a legal document (in privacy law) that discloses some or all of the ways a party gathers, uses, discloses, and manages a customer or client's data. It fulfills a legal requirement to protect a customer or client's privacy... [read more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_policy)

Having the user agree to the privacy policy puts you at a safe place as they're agreeing to your terms of how their data will be used. ***As long as your functionality is acting within the policy***.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware of the requirements of data processing under the GDPR. In essence you need to *inform* your customer of *what* information you are going to process, *why* you are processing it, *where* you store it, *who* you might share it with and *how long* you will retain it. This needs presenting in a notice at the point the data is captured. You must also inform your data subject of their *qualified rights* under the GDPR, how to contact your data officer and how to make a formal complaint to the Data Commissioner.

This can be a lot more simple than it sounds but I'd recommend getting an expert to cast an eye over your notices and whatever processes you put in place for the exercising of rights etc. - documentation is key; the ICO will want to see that everything has been considered and documented. Even if you choose to take no action on a point, as long as that decision is documented with justifiable reason, you are broadly compliant.

[These](https://www.priviness.eu/) guys are good and can certainly help you. A worthwhile investment, as falling foul of GDPR is likely to be expensive!

Steve.